# Using an IMG Map to display larger images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I am using an IMG Map that has many small pictures. When I hover over each image it will display a larger image. How do I do this? I do not mind using javascript, css, etc as long as it works. Please provide an example.

**HTML OF IMG MAP**

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="Main Photo - Please View With Images On"
usemap="#Map" class="center" style="width:900px;" border="0" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
 <area class="1" shape="rect" coords="4,3,225,150" />
 <area class="2" shape="rect" coords="2,152,221,303" />
 <area class="3" shape="rect" coords="3,303,221,452"  />
</map>
```

Each class would have a different image to display larger.

Comment: possible repetition of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745110/using-jquery-hover-with-html-image-map

Comment: suggest getting a tooltip plugin, easy to find in google. Store the image url in each area in a data attribute, pass it to plugin

Comment: @charlietfl - I have tried to use qTip 2 but has an issue, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131941/qtip-2-and-images

Comment: qtip can do a lot, but there are simpler API's for tooltips also that aren't as difficult to wade through a bazillion options and config settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like the below given fiddle. Code written is very rough & can be optimized. Just check you want this or something else.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3GF6s/3/

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems to work but has a few glitches. It will flicker on and off if you do not have the mouse positioned properly.

Comment: Yup! I know as said code is written roughly. You can style its according to your need.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster):

http://jsfiddle.net/zSBL5/

To make this work with its built-in tooltip API you need to do a couple things. First add an attribute to each area like this:

```
<area data-key="2,all"  shape="rect" coords="0,90,82,170" 
    href="http://www.shelterness.com/pictures/amazing-diy-photo-tiles-1-500x373.jpg" />
```

Note `data-key`. This is ImageMapster's "mapKey". The only reason we need it for your situation is to create a single area group called "all" that can be used to show the same tooltip for each area. Each area will have an attribute like this but with a different number, e.g. `data-key="3,all"`, `data-key="4,all"`, and so on.

Then here's the code to bind imagemapster:

```
$('img').mapster({
    toolTipContainer: $('#tooltip-container'),
    mapKey: 'data-key',
    areas: [ {
        key: 'all',
        toolTip: true
    }],
    showToolTip: true,
    onShowToolTip: function(data) {
        if (this.href && this.href!='#') {
            data.toolTip.html('<img src="'+this.href+'">');
        }
    }});​
```

Here's what each option means:

1) `toolTipContainer` should contain the HTML for a template to show the tooltip. In the fiddle, you'll see I added a hidden div with ID "tooltip-container"

2) `mapKey` is the name of the attribute you added to each area. This attribute can contain one or more comma separated values. Imagemapster groups together areas for highlighting that share the first value, so use different ones if you don't need to group any areas. The 2nd value should be the same for each area, I use this to activate tooltips for all areas.

3) `areas` is an array of area-specific formatting information. Usually you use this to control how the highlighting effects on each area are shown. In your case I'm just using it to activate tooltips for all areas. The key `all` matches every area, since they all have that as then 2nd key, and `toolTip: true` enables tooltips. Normally you would say `toolTip: "some text specific to this area:"` and that text would just get shown in your default tooltip container. In your case, we want to show an image, and I want to grab the image URL from the area itself, so I need to handle it in a function when the tooltip is shown.

4) `showToolTip` says enable tooltips for the whole map.

5) `onShowToolTip` defines a function that gets called whenever a tooltip is shown. From here you can intercept it and change the contents to show the image from that area.

This should be simpler - but the tooltip API in imagemapster is really designed around a very simple model where you just have some hardcoded text for each area. This is a workaround to grab the URL from the the href of each area.